# Categories whose coproducts are not disjoint

Tags: category-theory

I’m looking for examples of categories whose coproducts are not automatically disjoint.

A coproduct $X\rightarrow X\coprod Y\leftarrow Y$ is disjoint iff the pullback of the above diagram is an initial object.

I’ve considered **Set**, **Group** and **Top**, but all seem to have naturally disjoint coproducts.

In **Group** I expected non-disjoint coproducts since the underlying set of the coproduct of groups isn’t a disjoint union, but the pullbacks are singletons just like the initial group.

Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: What would disjoint mean in the abstract?

Comment: @Randall The coproduct of two objects is disjoint iff the kernel pair of their coprojections is an initial object. (and the coprojections are monic, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/disjoint+coproduct#idea)

Comment: You have to try some less conventional examples. For instance, say, a suitable partially ordered set considered as a category.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps this is a cheap example, but given a set $X$, its power set $2^X$ is in particular a poset by the inclusion relation, and is thus a category.
In this case, the coproduct of $U,V\subseteq X$ is given by their union, which is disjoint only if $U$ and $V$ were already disjoint as sets since
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
U\cap V @>>> U \\
@VVV @VVV \\
V @>>> U\cup V
\end{CD}
is a pullback square (and a pushout square).

Comment: I’d say elegant or canonical rather than cheap ;). Nice!

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example which is even a familiar category of algebraic objects: in commutative rings the coproduct is the tensor product $\otimes$, and it sometimes happens that the tensor product of two rings is the zero ring. In that case the pullback of the diagram you're looking at is just the product. So, for example, $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_3$ don't have a disjoint coproduct.

(However, coproducts *are* disjoint in the opposite category of affine schemes!)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your final comment: surely the opposite category of affine schemes is equivalent to the category of commutative rings? So your same example should work: the coproduct of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb F_2)$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb F_3)$ in the opposite category of affine schemes (i.e. the product in affine schemes) is the empty scheme, and the relevant pullback of the diagram is $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb F_2)\sqcup\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb F_3)$. This is not an initial object ($\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$).

Comment: @AlexanderBetts I believe Qiaochu meant "... in the opposite category, namely the category of affine schemes".  The claim is correct if interpreted that way.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Coproducts of affine schemes are disjoint, and in fact the category of affine schemes is extensive: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense!